# After upgrade magento 2.1.0 to 2.2.1 product export not working

Tags: magento2

After upgrade magento **2.1.0 to 2.2.1** product export redirect to dashboard.

Click on `System > Export` then choose entity type Product and then scroll and click on continue.

Its redirect to dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check database, core_config_data table. Run below query in DB

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value` = '0' WHERE `core_config_data`.`path` like 'advanced/modules_disable_output/Magento_AdminNotification';
```

This query enables the Admin Notification module and issue get resolved.
This works for me.